# org.jxls seems to affect log4j

Tags: log4j, jxls

When I add org.jxls dependency to pom,it seems to affect log4j outputs.I set log4j log level "ERROR",but it outputs DEBUG infomation to console.But when I remove org.jxls,log4j works right.

Answer (score 0):

Although Jxls-2 uses [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) as a logging facade it has a dependency to  [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) because it uses some if its XML processing utilities.

If you do not use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) but another logging framework (e.g. log4j) and configured [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) binding you can still end up with "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings" warning.

Currently there is a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/37/dont-obtrude-a-logging-framework-conflicts) in Jxls-2 to remove the [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) dependency.
Until it is fixed you may need to have a logback.xml in your classpath.

**Update**

The [issue](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/37/dont-obtrude-a-logging-framework-conflicts) is now resolved in JXLS v2.2.9 .

So now it should be possible to plugin any logging framework following the instructions in [SLF4J manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)